# R Multivariate Normal CDF

Tags: r, normal-distribution, cumulative-distribution-function

I am trying to estimate the CDF of a MVN distribution for some given ranges ([-Inf,mu], [mu,mu+3], [mu+3,Inf]). In R using package mvtnorm and function pmvnorm, with some dummy data:

```
mu=c(13,15,12)
co=matrix(c(6,2,3,2,4,2,3,2,5),nrow=3,byrow=T)

library(mvtnorm)
pmvnorm(lower=-Inf,
        upper=mu,
        mean=mu,
        sigma=co)[1]

pmvnorm(lower=mu,
        upper=mu+3,
        mean=mu,
        sigma=co)[1]

pmvnorm(lower=mu+3,
        upper=Inf,
        mean=mu,
        sigma=co)[1]
```

```
[1] 0.2415246
[1] 0.1123291
[1] 0.01065227
```

Clearly this does not sum to 1, even though I went from -Inf to Inf. Why not?

Also, if I try to estimate one of the ranges as the differences of the current minus the previous, for ex. for the last interval in [mu+3,Inf] = [-Inf,Inf] - [-Inf,mu+3]:

```
pmvnorm(lower=-Inf,upper=Inf,mean=mu,sigma=co)[1]-
pmvnorm(lower=-Inf,upper=mu+3,mean=mu,sigma=co)[1]
```

```
[1] 0.2010412
```

The result is different from the previous estimate. Why?

Comment: Simplify your question to two variables and draw planar pictures of the events whose probabilities you are computing: the resolution of the problem will be evident.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first `pmvnorm`  calculates the probability that `variable 1 <=13` AND `variable 2 <=15` AND `variable <=12` all occurs at the same time. The probability that each individual variable fufills that criteria will be 0.5, however the joint probability will not be 0.5

If we use an example where all variables are uncorrelated

```
mu=c(13,15,12)
co=matrix(c(1,0.0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1),nrow=3,byrow=T)

pmvnorm(lower=-Inf,
        upper=mu,
        mean=mu,
        sigma = co)
```

This returns

```
[1] 0.125
```

This is the probability comes from the probability of three uncorrelated events happening at the same time, i.e. `0.5^3 = 0.125`. In your data the variables seems to be correlated, which is the reason that probability is greater than 0.125.

Basically the reason that the sum of probabilities does not equal one is that the calculations above doesn't include all possible coordinates. For example the coordinates could be `(10, 17,14)`, which isn't included.

As for the difference in the estimate, I believe that the `pmvnorm` use some sort of sampling algorithm with may lead to differences in probability.

Comment: So how would you estimate the CDF for ex. in the range [0,3] for all possible values when correlated? Regarding the second part, the algorithm uses approximations so we can expect small differences, however in my case the difference is between 0.01065227 and 0.2010412, this is clearly wrong.

Comment: To calculate in the range [0,3] just use the code that generated 0.1123291. For the second concern: The value 0.010 is the probability that ALL variables are greater that mu+3. The 0.2010412 is the probability that atleast one of the variables are greater than mu+3. Make sure to seperate the individual probabilities and the joint probability.